# Nominees' Stats on Election Page

Tags: support, election, flagging, moderator-tools

This is a screenshot of [msh210's (current pro-tem moderator) nomination page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-17625) for the [2012 Mi Yodeya election](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/election/1):

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, there is a listed number of helpful flags (well over 200 for msh210). However, as of now msh210 does not have a [Deputy badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/65/deputy). We speculated that perhaps the listed helpful flag count is influenced by various moderator actions and does not parallel the count for the [Deputy badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/65/deputy), but it seemed odd that [IsaacMoses's nomination](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-17624) (not shown) listed only 8 helpful flags, and we all know IsaacMoses is more helpful than that.

So what exactly do the listed stats represent? And if relevant, how are moderator actions counted vis-a-vis "flag weight" and the [Deputy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/65/deputy)/[Marshal](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/84/marshal) badges?

Comment: @msh210 I was being retro: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103406/166155

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Deputy and Marshal badges are only granted to registered users - not moderators.  The count of helpful flags shown on the election nomination screen is in fact correct - msh210 does have a lot of helpful flags (specifically on comments).

Isaac does in fact show a few helpful flags however, this isn't the entire story as far as who is more helpful in contributing to your community.  I suggest looking at the entire story (posts, comments, and general contributions) to make a well informed decision about who you'd like to see as your next moderator.

Comment: That seems odd (that mods can't get the badge; they are the Marshals and Deputies _par excellance_ around here) but if you say so I believe you. And don't worry: my question was purely about how it works. I know IsaacMoses does plenty of work on this site :)

Comment: Hmm [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119778/166155) implies that Bill the Lizard got his Marshal badge after becoming mod. Have things changed since then?

Comment: @DoubleAA That was back when the badges were powered by flag weight rather than a count of raised flags.

Comment: @AnnaLear So the mod rule was changed at the same time coincidentally? I don't see what the metric has to do with whether or not a mod should get it.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm guessing here, but I think the implementation was changed when, well, the implementation for the badges changed. Looks like it's intentional either way.